# Iframe with pdf with overlaying div fails in IE/Safari/Opera

Tags: javascript, pdf, html, iframe, onclick

I have an Iframe overlayed by a div - in order to catch onClick events.
The bare code works if the iFrame does not contain .pdf:

```
<div style="position:relative;">

<iframe id="bigpdf" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:none;" frameborder="0">
<p>Alt text</a></p>
</iframe>

<div id="bigframe" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:none; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;" onclick="$('#bigframe, #bigpdf').hide(); ('#pdfphoto').show();">Top</div>
</div>

<div id="pdfphoto" onclick="$('#bigframe, #bigpdf').show(); $('#pdfphoto').hide();"> &nbsp;</div>
```

When 'pdfphoto' is clicked, the iframe 'bigpdf' and overlayed div 'bigframe' is shown.
When the overlaying 'bigframe' div is clicked it reverses.

However, when the content of the iframe is a .pdf, this is loaded as the iframe is set to visible the div is ignored in IE/Safari/Opera as the pdf to come into focus.

How can I bring the overlaying div to the front and in focus again...

- [View jsfiddle here (simplified version)](http://jsfiddle.net/zq57j/5/)
- [Safari toggle pdf problem solved here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190842/iframe-jquery-toggle-fails-to-hide-pdf-in-safari)

Comment: Demo in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zq57j/

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - why do you have the overlay div? Maybe the browser doesn't like you overlaying HTML elements over a 3rd party element like a PDF.

Comment: In general, you cannot add an onClick to an Iframe. Placing a div over it solves this problem. However, in IE, the overlaying div is ignored when the content is a pdf (probably as the pdf tool bar takes over). Any other solution would be fine - but have tried a lot...

Comment: Why do you want to add an `onclick`?

Comment: To hide the pdf when it is clicked...

Comment: That doesn't seem like intuitive UX design. Wouldn't the user want to interact with the PDF document? Selecting text, scrolling, whatever. Why not have a close button around the edge somewhere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41512/discussion-between-morten-repsdorph-husfeldt-and-frits-van-campen)